# 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 AdMob

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

When I implement AdMob in Unity and Build in iOS, I get an error.
I think it may have something to do with AdConoly's mediation.

```
duplicate symbol '_GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsSetTestMode' in:
    /Users/haru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-euiznbperzppidadewaqzqmozuws/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsInterface-0bde5dbdd0968a7533938e67d817fddd.o
    /Users/haru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-euiznbperzppidadewaqzqmozuws/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsInterface-8a9183f109e10dc60b472c5580908796.o
duplicate symbol '_GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsIsTestMode' in:
    /Users/haru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-euiznbperzppidadewaqzqmozuws/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsInterface-0bde5dbdd0968a7533938e67d817fddd.o
    /Users/haru/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-euiznbperzppidadewaqzqmozuws/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GADUMAdColonyAppOptionsInterface-8a9183f109e10dc60b472c5580908796.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can Build be successful?

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you use both UNITY and Google SDKs. You should use resolve the google dependencies (force resolve). if it does not work, shut down unity and  you better back up your project and then go find duplicated files in file directory of your app. then delete the duplicated files. this should work.